how to draw a chart with OLed and micropython
I have an O led ,an esp32 and i use this micro python Library to make simple things like writing something, but now I want to draw a chart and do some calculations, but I don't know how to draw. please help.
Ai is not work on this issue.

but my oled is sh1106

@user24714692 matplotlib is no help on MicroPython, but this discussion on the MicroPython forum archive has some links that might be useful.

The micropython-nano-gui library by Peter Hinch has a plotting module.
